# Why does devise me redirect me to /users instead of /users/edit when my account update fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

The problem is like this:

If I use the default registration controller I get redirected:

- **/users/edit** to **root** when user update **succeeds**
- **/users/edit** to **/users** when update **fails**

Because the default controller update action looks like this:

```
if resource_updated
  sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
  respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

`after_update_path_for` is set by default to `root`

If update **fails** I get the devise error messages and `hasError` div wrappers for the fields with error

In my `registrations controller` in the `edit` action I attribute values to a variable `@myvar={2, 3}`

This variable is used in the `registrations_edit` **view**

**Whenever user update fails I get error `no method .each for nil`** for my `@myvar`

How should I declare my view variables such that they are accessible even when update form fails?!

I have tried:

Forcing the controller to redirect to `edit` view no matter what:

```
if resource_updated
  sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
end
```

This created problems because devise validations do not work anymore

Edit-------

My registrations edit:

```
def edit
  @images = Dir.glob("public/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/*")
end
```

My view:

```
<% img_paths = Array.new %>
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
  <%img_paths.push([
    '',
    "/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/original/#{image.split('/').last}",
    {'data-img-src'=>"/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/#{image.split('/').last}"}
    ])%>
  <% end %>
```

Edit-----

Registration controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def edit
    @images = Dir.glob("public/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/*")
  end

  def update
    if params[:image_file_path]
      ff = File.open("public/"+params[:image_file_path])
      resource.image = ff
      resource.save!
    end
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end


  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :telephone, :image, :address, :birthday)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :telephone, :image, :image_file_path, :address, :birthday)
  end

  protected 

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you share your registration controller? , also if you are customizing devise registration then you have to ensure @images variable should pass to view in both the condition 1) success and 2) failed.

Comment: Have you seen if update fail then it will not call 'edit', thats the reason it is giving error, So I think it wold be good if you set image variable before update

Comment: I am confused. `@image` variable is set in `#edit` action. Where exactly should I insert images to ensure it is available if update fails? I have tried to call `#edit` if update fails but then I lose all my devise validations and error messages. @Arv

Comment: I don't understand which is called when how where. AllI need is to make `@images` available in my edit view no mater what action is called. @Arv

Comment: Try this may be it helps you before_filter :update

'
def set_images
  @images = Dir.glob("public/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/*")
end'

Comment: @Arv could you please write this as an answer and add the code to my registration controller? I cannot understand how filters work, and I can't get it to work by myself. I am reading the documentation right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72979/discussion-between-arv-and-vlad-otrocol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this;-

```
def update
    if params[:image_file_path]
      ff = File.open("public/"+params[:image_file_path])
      resource.image = ff
      resource.save!
    end
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
    @images = Dir.glob("public/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/*")

      clean_up_passwords resource

      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get redirected, all the controller instance variables get dumped, so there's no way to get around that except saving the data you need in some place that's propagated through the redirect. One such place is in a `flash` message (if you need a string and use it just once).

Another option is to store that in the `session` and pick it up on the other side.

I could tell you more if you paste your `registrations#edit`  action in the question.